# Change innerHTML when display style of certain element is "block"

Tags: javascript, html

I have this "slideshow" here where you can get to the next slide by click. I want to have the same button but different text for every image. So I tried to change the innerHTML of the "active" var when one of the "mySlides" vars is set to block.
But it won't recognize it.. Can you help me?

```js
// JavaScript Document

var active = document.getElementById("active"),
   x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

var slideIndex = 1;
 showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
 var i,
  dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  
 
 if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1;
 } 
 
 if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length;
 }
 
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none";
 }
 
 for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
   dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
 }
  
 x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
 dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}


function visible() {
 
 if (x[0].style.display = "block") {
  active.innerHTML = "test";
 }
 
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
 <div id ="slider-wrapper">
  <img id="img1" class="centerscreen mySlides slidepos fade" src="x.jpg" alt="picture1">
  <img id="img2" class="centerscreen mySlides slidepos fade" src="xy.jpg" alt="picture2">
  <img id="img3" class="centerscreen mySlides slidepos fade" src="xyz.jpg" alt="picture3"></div>
  <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white centerscreen badgepos">
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
  </div>
    <container id="buttons" class="centerscreen">
    <div id="navarrow-left" class="w3-left w3-hover-text-black btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div id="navarrow-right" class="w3-right w3-hover-text-black btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
 </container>
</div>

<div id="active">
 Centerbutton
</div>
```

Comment: You never call `visible()`

Comment: What I see right off the bat is `if (x[0].style.display = "block") {` is going to set the display to block and always be true.  You should use `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below

```js
// JavaScript Document


var pictureText = Array("Picture1", "Picture2", "Picture3", "Picture4");

var active = document.getElementById("active"),
   x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

var slideIndex = 1;

showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
 var i,
  dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  
 
 if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1;
 } 
 
 if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length;
 }
 
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none";
 }
 
 for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
   dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
 }
  
 x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
 dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
  
  visible(slideIndex); 
}


function visible(slideIndex) {
  
  document.getElementById("img"+slideIndex).style.display = "none";
 active.innerHTML = pictureText[slideIndex]; 
}
```

```css
.navarrow-left{
  float: left;
}
.navarrow-right{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
 <div id ="slider-wrapper">
  <img id="img1" class="centerscreen mySlides slidepos fade" src="x.jpg" alt="picture1">
  <img id="img2" class="centerscreen mySlides slidepos fade" src="xy.jpg" alt="picture2">
  <img id="img3" class="centerscreen mySlides slidepos fade" src="xyz.jpg" alt="picture3"></div>
  <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white centerscreen badgepos">
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
  </div>
    <container id="buttons" class="centerscreen">
    <div id="navarrow-left" class="w3-left w3-hover-text-black btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div id="navarrow-right" class="w3-right w3-hover-text-black btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
 </container>
</div>

<div id="active"></div>
```

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I needed. Thank you, I hope my skills will get better soon..